# Assign unique number on an Insert statement with starting value other than 1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the `INSERT` statement shown below and I would like to insert a unique value into column `JPM_ITEM_KEY_ID` per row through, but I need to have the number start at the current `MAX` value already populated in this column + 1, and increment by 1 from there for each row. This is not a primary key column and has a data type of `decimal(12,0)`

```
INSERT INTO PS_JPM_JP_ITEMS  (JPM_PROFILE_ID, JPM_CAT_TYPE, JPM_CAT_ITEM_ID, EFFDT, EFF_STATUS, JPM_ITEM_KEY_ID) 
    SELECT 
        HL.JPM_PROFILE_ID, HL.EDLVLACHV, 
        [Map to JPM_CAT_ITEM_ID], EFFDT, EFF_STATUS, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY HL.JPM_PROFILE_ID) 
    FROM 
        #TempHighLevel AS HL
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        #TempSchoolingFromTalent AS S ON HL.GHS_OC_ID = S.GHS_OC_ID 
                                      AND HL.[Map to JPM_CAT_ITEM_ID] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = S.JPM_CAT_ITEM_ID
    WHERE
        S.GHS_OC_ID IS NULL
        AND HL.JPM_PROFILE_ID IS NOT NULL
```

Current data:

```
JPM_PROFILE_ID  Map to JPM_CAT_TYPE    Map to JPM_CAT_ITEM_ID   EFFDT        EFF_STATUS  JPM_ITEM_KEY_ID
100004          EDLVLACHV              2NN                      2010-09-20   A           1
100010          EDLVLACHV              DNN                      2019-11-13   A           2
100011          EDLVLACHV              DNN                      2021-01-13   A           3
100013          EDLVLACHV              DNN                      2017-12-05   A           4
100015          EDLVLACHV              BSN                      2016-12-06   A           5
```

Is there a way I can use `ROW_NUMBER` or another function and start at a different value other and 1 and increment from there? Ideally I would want to start at the `MAX` number already in this column (1135814) + 1 and go from there...

Comment: I may have figured it out - `SELECT 1135814 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY HL.JPM_PROFILE_ID) AS 'JPM_ITEM_KEY_ID' FROM #TempHighLevel as HL` This seems to work.

Comment: How does this columm currently get its value, and why would you use decimal with zero decimal places - that's an integer!

Comment: I didnt build the table, it's an application built table and is defined as such. I believe there is application level code that is assigning the values to this field currently.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an identity specification on that column, you could then specify the seed number (number you start at) and the increment as well
[image]

The issue with this is that the table would have to be dropped and recreated.

Also, I'm sure you probably inherited this database design (as most of us have) but in case you haven't I highly recommend this article on database naming conventions, I've been using it for nearly a decade and makes my code so much cleaner.

https://weblogs.asp.net/jamauss/DatabaseNamingConventions

Comment: Yes and I wouldnt want to alter the existing values already in this column...

Comment: I'm not sure if those values would remain when you transfer over the data and back.  If you have a dev environment or can create tables in your current environment you could whip up another table that looks exactly like this one aside from that field having an identity spec.  Copy over all the data and see if it allows you to insert into that field.  Also, if there are foreign keys it will make this job harder.